# Outlook: How can you automatically sync appointments from my Outlook calendar to a public Outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is it possible to automatically sync specific appointments from my personal Outlook calendar to a shared public Outlook calendar?  In order to meet my needs, the sync needs to be automatic and not require a 3rd-party tool.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/transfer-calendars-between-outlook-and-google-calendar-HA010167495.aspx) are the methods that Microsoft lists as means to synchronize Outlook 2007 and Google Calendar. The only automatic means I have been able to find to sync Google Calendar with Outlook is by using Google Calendar Sync (a 3rd party tool), which is shown in the link.
Other than *maybe* Microsoft's Live mail I doubt that there would be any other Public Calendar options which would have a means to sync with Outlook without some sort of 3rd party app being installed on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm actually trying to syncronize my Outlook calendar with a shared Outlook calendar. I have a team and we're trying to syncronize individual appointments to the shared calendar to use for team planning. I've updated the question to be more clear.