# Outlook as register tool

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar

Is it possible to open a shared calendar in outlook, which synchronises (one way) with one personal calendar?

This way, a group can place appointments in the shared calendar, which appear in the personal calendar. This way, the whole group can see where there's space, so no doubles take place. (in this case, workers can schedule appointments with the manager)

This functionality would probably also answer [this](https://superuser.com/questions/209362/outlook-how-can-you-automatically-sync-appointments-from-my-outlook-calendar-to) question.

Comment: Are you running an exchange server?  If so, you can create a public folder and then place a calendar inside that everyone can see.

Comment: Jep, we're running exchange... but is it possible to sync the calendar with one person (one way)